# Python 3 import behaviour differences between operating systems

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm probably in need of some major sleep, but this is making it hard for me to even consider it.

I have the following structure in 2 separate machines:

```
.
├── testmod
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test.py
└── testmod2
    ├── __init__.py
    └── hello.py
```

The machines in question are:

- CentOS (Linux release 7.2.1511)
- macOS Sierra (10.12.4)

I'm most definitely running Python 3.6 on both machines:

> Python 3.6.1 (default, Apr  7 2017, 09:32:32) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red
>   Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
>
> Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5050, Mar 21 2017, 01:21:04) [GCC 4.2.1
>   (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin

The only file with content is test.py:

```
from testmod2 import hello

print(hello)
```

From the root dir (where testmod and testmod2 coexist), I'm running the following command:

```
python3.6 testmod/test.py
```

macOS output:

```
<module 'testmod2.hello' from '/Users/joao/Documents/tests/testmod2/hello.py'>
```

Centos output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testmod/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from testmod2 import hello
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'testmod2'
```

I'm stumped. What have I obviously missed here?

Comment: I think you need an `__init__.py` in the root directory.

Comment: Just attempted that, negative, same results.

Comment: Is root in the PATH on one machine but not the other?

Comment: `testmod2/__init__py` - if that's not just a typo *in the question*, you really do need some sleep ;-)

Comment: @LukasGraf, apologies, that has been corrected - it was just a typo

Comment: For the record, I get the CentOS results with both Python 2.7 and 3.5 on Ubuntu Xenial.

Comment: Add the output of `python3.6 -m site` on both machines.

Comment: I tested this on CentOS 7 and on OS X 10.12.4. In **both cases**, as expected, you get a traceback. Your code only works if I add ``PYTHONPATH=`pwd` `` before my `python3.6` command.

Comment: @wim, I've edited the post with the output of python3.6 -m site

Comment: @joaodlf: the `python3.6 -m site` test will auto-add the current working directory to the path, always, regardless of wether or not it is already stated in `PYTHONPATH`. Can you cd to a different directory first, *then* run it? Or show `echo $PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: On macOS the absolute path to `hello.py` is `/Users/joao/Documents/tests/testmod2/hello.py`.  What is the absolute path to `hello.py` on CentOS?

Comment: Put differently: I'm 99.9% certain you have `/Users/joao/Documents/tests` on your `PYTHONPATH` on OS X, but do not have `/var/tests` in your `PYTHONPATH` on CentOS.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Regardless of where I run the -m site command, the only output difference is the first item in sys.path (which is always the same as whatever dir I'm in), $PYTHONPATH is empty in Centos, on OSX it contains my apache-spark dirs, which I expect anyway (I have physically added those months ago)

Comment: @wim: The absolute path for hello.py in CentOS is /var/tests/testmod2

Comment: @MartijnPieters: that has fixed it indeed! Adding the /var/tests to PYTHONPATH, that is. I'm not entirely sure why it's needed, though. As I said before, my PYTHONPATH in macOS does not contain /Users/joao/Documents/tests

Comment: I am creating these directories on the fly, it seems a bit silly that I might have to edit the PYTHONPATH for every project directory under CentOS.

Comment: The directory a script is in is automatically part of the PYTHONPATH; this is not the same as the current working directory. If you expected `testmod` to be a package on the path, don't run scripts in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else wondering, my $PYTHONPATH was not set at all in CentOS. I suspect others might run into the same issue, so a solution *could* be:

```
export PYTHONPATH="."
```

Although this will work, it's not really recommended to add a relative path to $PYTHONPATH - It's probably wiser to add the absolute path where your code resides:

```
export PYTHONPATH="/your/python/code"
```

(a more permanent solution is of course to add the above to your **~/.bashrc** or similar)

Comment: Right, so PYTHONPATH was not set at all first, then set to `:/nonsense`. It is the *empty path* before the colon that is the active element here, having the same meaning as `pwd`.  That's because it is seen as a relative path and made absolute by adding it to the current working directory.

Comment: Using `export PYTHONPATH=""` should do the same. Or more explicitly: `export PYTHONPATH="."`

Comment: Thank you Martijn! That makes a lot more sense now. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Note that it is still a bad idea to add a relative path to a global `PYTHONPATH`. You can trivially break a Python program merely by being in the wrong direction, and having a module name there that masks a dependency. Try to run `pip` when you are in a directory with a `requests.py` module, for example.

Comment: Is there an easy way to circumvent these issues? I would prefer not having to edit the $PYTHONPATH every time I create a new code directory. This isn't the case in osx, either.

Comment: If you want to treat `testmod` as a *package*, you should not be running a script inside of that package. See [Execution of Python code with -m option or not](//stackoverflow.com/q/22241420) for better options (using a package as a script with the `-m` flag). That way the parent directory of `testmod` is automatically part of the module search path too.

Comment: The other option is to make sure your scripts are not inside a package but are top-level files. Move `test.py` *out* of `testmod` and into the top-level directory, and you again automatically get the right parent directory added to the path.

Comment: Thanks for the input, again. I've edited the answer to try and not steer others into making that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I see that on Centos the script dir is not prepended to your sys.path. On my Ubuntu box it is prepended and everything works. I found the following doc on the topic: [The python command has a new option, -I, which causes it to run in “isolated mode”, which means that sys.path contains neither the script’s directory...](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#changes-in-python-command-behavior)

Maybe you need to check what options are used when python runs by default.